# Significance of pie-charts in representing sufficient-cause components

Tags: data-visualization, causality, treatment-effect, counterfactuals

In the book *[Causal Inference - What If](https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/miguel-hernan/wp-content/uploads/sites/1268/2023/07/hernanrobins_WhatIf_19jul23.pdf)*, the authors present a form of *pie-chart-type* diagram to represent sufficient-cause components (refer to figure 5.1 on page 64 and figure 5.2 on page 65 respectively). Below are some details of the context.
My query is - ***do these pie-charts (the areas of the portions) have some quantitative significance as well? If yes, what type of quantitative information? If no, can they be represented equally well in a, table format, say?***

**Context:**
In figure 5.2, shown below, $A$ and $E$ are two treatments. $A=1$ represents a treatment of heart transplant; $E=1$ a treatment of supplying vitamins. Outcome $Y=1$ represents death. $U_i$ is the respective background factor; together with $A$ and $E$ they form the sufficient causes for different groups of people developing the outcome $Y=1$.
For example, the second pie-chart (row 1, column 2) represents a certain group of people who would develop the outcome $Y=1$ under treatment $A=1$ and with background factors $U_1=1$, irrespective of the state of the treatment $E$.

[image]